# Rails Create and Edit on the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, crud

I am trying to accomplish Create and Edit on the same view (and same controller) on Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.2. I have a partial and I am using `form_for` and the standard form helpers.

I submit using Ajax, so my page (form) is not refreshed or redirected. When the user tries to edit the form, naturally, Rails will create an entry instead of updating it. I was thinking of modifying the **Controller**'s `create` method to detect existing entries, but I am not sure if this is the correct approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty easily include the same form in both create and edit pages by storing it in a partial (typically `_form.html.erb`) and rendering the form in both create and edit.

This is what `rails generate scaffold MODEL FIELD:TYPE FIELD1:TYPE1` will give you, as well.

Comment: I ended up just re-rendering the whole form; Rails is nice in that it takes care of the POST or PUT action. The question was about using the same form to accomplish either a create or edit on the same page. I don't have an edit or create, just a blank form.